# Could you determine the best places where to put logging that will help to troubleshoot issues?

Tags: logging

Could you determine the best places where to put logging that will help to troubleshoot issues?

I have two points:
- put log messages in the if-else logic, at least after cycle;
- at the beginning and in the end of the valuable part.

The application is the Java service with whom are communicating web UI and C++ agent.

Any idea?

Comment: Going to need a lot more context than that. For example is this a windows app, iPhone app, web app, or other?

Comment: The application is the Java service with whom are communicating web UI and C++ agent.

Comment: Better. You'll get more on track responses.

Comment: I am interested in logging rules for  server(Java service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found several not bad sources, which finally helped me:

http://www.slideshare.net/ardentlearner/exception-handling-and-logging-best-practices-v1

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/10-tips-proper-application-logging.html